How to replace the direct dependency `A` with all transitive dependencies of `A` in the artifact pom.xml?
I have a maven project named A which is dependent on artifacts B and C, I want to generate a thin jar which will have only the classes of A, B and C from project A with As pom. I can do this using maven-shade-plugin, but the problem is the resultant artifact have 3 separate pom files,each with their own set of dependencies. Now How do I replace  of B and C in A with their transitive dependencies?
I want to see if maven already has some solution to this instead of me manually updating pom of A
Tried true in maven-shade-plugin, didn't see any change.

I am not really sure what you want. If you want to exclude all transitive dependencies coming through B and C, you can use <exclusion>.

I can exclude them, but the problem is when I am consuming artifact A in some other application, it throws an error saying it's not finding excluded classes in the classpath. Because these transitive dependencies are not mentioned in the pom.xml, they are not pulled into the application classpath. I want excluded classes to be taken from where the artifact A is consumed. This is only possible when the missing transitive dependencies of 'BandCare promoted toAs dependencies and are present in A` pom.xml

If A is a library to be consumed by other artifacts, it should include the classes of B and C in the first place, at least in most scenarios I can think of.

Yes it will be consumed by other artifacts, that is where the problem comes from. It includes the classes of B and C already. Only thing A lacks now is dependencies of B and C, so the artifact that consumes A cannot resolve transitive dependencies of B and C unless they are included to pom of A.

Why does it include the classes of B and C? Why not make B and C separate artifacts as usual?
